# iOS 17.1.1 on iPhone SE 2nd Gen PANIC MODE PROBLEM

Tags: iphone, ios, battery, kernel-panic

[image]

Could someone please interpret this panic message for me? It started to cause my iPhone to shut down a couple of weeks ago. Battery is in good condition, no water damage or big falls, no storage issues, etc. I am trying to figure out if it is worth trying to fix, or if I should just buy a new phone. I’ve already spent a hundred dollars on the new battery, screen, protector and case.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Do you have Bosch EasyControl or Bosch Smart Home [or any other Bosch app, Google finds quite a few] installed? If so, uninstall, update or contact Bosch.

Comment: This would be a good time to run Backup https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977

Comment: After that run IOS restore https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263